# helper thread checking filesystem resources

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am running http server which serves requests constantly.
I would like to have separate "helper" thread, checking if directory in filesystem is available.
If the resource is gone, then I would like this helper thread to return value to main thread so I can stop the http server.

```
def main():
    os.chdir(root)
    server = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 80), MyHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

I was thinking about sth like

```
def foo(bar, baz):
  print 'hello {0}'.format(bar)
  return 'foo' + baz

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

async_result = pool.apply_async(foo, ('world', 'foo')) # tuple of args for foo

# do some other stuff in the main process

return_val = async_result.get()  # get the return value from your function.
```

and stop the server if return_val == "stop"

Is it the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're willing to drop the async stuff (because honestly i don't see your justification for needing it)
you can just do

```
while foo():
    server.handle_request()
```

instead of `server.serve_forever()`

if you really want to do the check asynchronously you need to show a bit more code of how you intend to use it, do you want it to check constantly? once in a while? triggered by some event?

edit: you can still use a while loop just with the if inside

```
while True:
    if foo():
        server.handle_request()
    else:
        sleep(1) # or if foo is blocking (like when accessing the file system) you can just not sleep
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. The thing is - the directory the server is using could be gone for lets say 1 minute and then back. So i want to shutdown the server for that 1 minute and then start it again when directory is back

Comment: I suppose sth like this would do the trick - 2 while loops `while True: while:foo(): server.handle_request() time.sleep(60) os.chdir(dir)`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with check in separate thread anyway,
it was as simple as that:

```
import threading

def background_check:
    (...)

backgroundCheck = threading.Thread(target=backround_check, args=[directory])
backgroundCheck.start()
```